# ACF field display on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've got an issue. I've created a custom field via ACF wordpress plugin. Its a field to custom post type categories (lets say its an additional description to the category). I've tried to add it to my page via such code:

```
$return_html.= '<h2 class="ppb_menu_title" ';
$return_html.= '>'.$menu_term->name.'</h2><br class="clear"/><br/>';
$displaytitle = the_field('category_subtitle');
$return_html.= '<div class="subtitledesc">'.$displaytitle.'</div>';
```

below code is a part of full page of code which you can find here [lines 1712-1715]:
https://codeshare.io/50QzqL

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: When you pass rest of the content it shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()` and include the term ID.

`get_field()` returns a value.

`the_field()` echoes a value.

Try this: `get_field('category_subtitle', 'term_' . $menu_term->term_id)`

Comment: I've tried both. Unfortunatelly it returns nothing. While checking the source ive noticed it shows my div container but without any value

Comment: What happens if you move `$displaytitle = ` above `if(isset($menu_term->name))`?

Comment: @JuliaGalden Try accessing the value via `term_id`.  Answer is updated.

Comment: @JuliaGalden Try this: `get_field('category_subtitle', 'term_' . $menu_term->term_id)`

Answer (score 1):

get_field() with a single parameter only works on the current post within the loop iirc, so you will have to provide a target if you're trying to get data for a category.

You'll need the termid of your category (when you're on a taxonomy-page, `$term = get_queried_object(); $termid = $term->term_id;` should work), then use get_field like so:

```
get_field( 'category_subtitle', "taxonomyname_$termid" );
get_field( 'category_subtitle', $term ); // if you have a term object
```

Further reading: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/